# How to get file name which is last created and starts with word "backup"?

Tags: posix

How to get file name which is last created and starts with word "backup" ?
I have listed directory like

```
DIR *dir;
struct dirent *ent;
if ((dir = opendir (directory.c_str())) != NULL) {
  while ((ent = readdir (dir)) != NULL) {
    string name(ent->d_name);
  }
  closedir (dir);
} else {
  /* could not open directory */
  perror ("");
  return "EXIT_FAILURE";
}
```

but how to get metadata when is created ?

Comment: You can use `stat`, or maybe better run `ls -lc backup*` and get the last...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `stat` to get lots of information about a file. The output of `stat` is a `struct stat`. `struct stat` contains the following member data:

```
           struct timespec st_atim;  /* time of last access */
           struct timespec st_mtim;  /* time of last modification */
           struct timespec st_ctim;  /* time of last status change */
```

Is that enough for your needs?

More information on `stat` can be found in [its man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html).